# How to make a conditional statement if an exception is raised during a function call?

Tags: jquery, python-2.7, bottle, raise

I am needing to return conditional content back to a jQuery `getJSON()` function from a Python script.

The Python script checks whether a user is logged in with:

```
aaa.require()
```

The `require` function has a built in `bottle.redirect` on authorisation failure, but that just communicates directly to the Python script, whereas I need to pass that message back to jQuery.

There is an exception class called `AuthException` that is raised on authorisation failure.

Can I do something like:

```
aaa.require()
if AuthException:
    # send something back to jQuery
```

In other words, is it possible to make a conditional statement based on whether an exception is raised during a function call?

Comment: Are you using [cork](http://cork.firelet.net/)?

Comment: Yes, so classes are [here](https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/bottle-cork/blob/master/cork/cork.py#L45) and start getting raised [here](https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/bottle-cork/blob/master/cork/cork.py#L154).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Cork, catch the `AuthException` exception raised only if you didn't set the  `fail_redirect` keyword; you can then just catch that exception:

```
from cork.cork import AuthException

try:
    aaa.require()
except AuthException as ae:
    # send back a JSON response
```

Comment: That makes sense, it is not working as intended (500 on the getJSON but run the .py file from terminal and no errors), my import statement is `from cork import Cork`.  Can I still reference `AuthException` the way you have demonstrated?

Comment: The [documentation](http://cork.firelet.net/#cork.cork.AuthException) states you need to import from `cork.cork`, so with the additional import, yes.